# Deploying asp.net solution to multiple websites

Tags: teamcity, web-deployment, azure-powershell

I'm currently running a web solution , that a deployed to multiple azure cloud web roles , the only difference for each web role is web.config , though I'm trying to automatize the process. I'm using now azure powershell + console application to write web.config before each deploy for a specific webrole. Is there any better way to do this ? Does teamcity or any other tools can achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it is possible for every CI server, not only TeamCity.
Fastest (but not cleanest) way would be to create as many build configurations, as you have web roles, implement web.config transform for it, and let MSBuild do it's magic further by deploying your application, running different build configurations.